# Prove $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} = \ln (a)$ without using L'hospital's.

Tags: limits, derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function, riemann-sum

I'm a Calc 2 student and was curious as to why $\frac{d}{dx}a^x = a^x\ln a$. Using the limit definition you can arrive at $\frac{d}{dx}a^x = \lim \limits_{h \to 0}  \frac{a^x(a^h-1)}{h}$ so the part of the limit involving $h$ must be $\ln (a)$. I was thinking it'd be cool to use the definition of $e^x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ by setting $y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and solving for $x$ which I'm guessing yields some sort of sum representation for $\ln(x)$.

Given the above I have a couple questions.

- How can I turn a limit expression such as $\lim \limits_{h \to 0}  \frac{(a^h-1)}{h}$ into a Riemann sum and vice versa?
- How would someone go about solving for $x$ in $y =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$

I know there are prob way easier ways to figure that out, but I'm curious as to whether this way of solving it works and how it pans out.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition for $\log(x)$? Any answer will change depending on what you are starting with.

Comment: Hint: calling the limit $f(a)$, prove $f$ is strictly increasing with $f(a^b)=bf(a)$. Now consider the special case $b=1/f(a)$.

Comment: $a^x = \exp (x\ln a)$. Use the chain rule for the derivative of $\exp (f(x))$.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on what you use as the _defintion_ of $a^x$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Troubles understanding this limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261964/troubles-understanding-this-limit)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1491220/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/540816/42969

Answer (score 2):

Since you used power series:

$$\frac{a^h-1}h=\frac{e^{h\log a}-1}h=\frac1h\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{h^n\log^na}{n!}-1\right)=\frac1h\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{h^n\log^na}{n!}=$$

$$=\log a+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{h^{n-1}\log^na}{n!}\xrightarrow[h\to0]{}\log a$$

Comment: Is there something off with the second-last equality in the first line? I think you're forgetting the $n!$ but that leads to an inequality, not an equality. In any case, squeeze theorem does the trick following your work and it was good that you saw the power series definition.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer You're completely right: thank you! I shall edit.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use the definition that $a^x$ (for positive $a$) is the unique continuous function satisfying $f(0) = 1, f(1) = a, f(x+y) = f(x) * f(y)$.

From this definition, we can prove that $(a^b)^x = a^{bx}$ as follows : We want to prove that $a^{bx}$ satisfies the above properties. Clearly , $a^{b0} = a^0 = 1$, and $a^{b1} = a^b$. $a^{b(x+y)} = a^{bx + by} = a^{bx} a^{by}$.

Now use [any of the standard arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function) to show that the above definition of $e^x$ is equivalent to any of the others (the above definition is characterization 5
in the article). By another standard argument, $\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$.

By defining $ln(x)$ to be the inverse of $e^x$, we have $e^{ln(a)} = a$, so $a^x = (e^{ln(a)}) ^x  = e^{x ln(a)}$. Now just use the chain rule to get $\frac{d}{dx} a^x = a^x ln(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $a^x=1+\frac{x\ln a }{1!}+\frac{(x\ln a) ^2}{2!}+O(x^3)$
Then $$L=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h \ln a+(h \ln a)^2/2+O(h^3)}{h}=\ln a$$

Comment: How do you get that series without the derivative of $a^x$?

Comment: Using Taylor for $e^{x\ln a}$

Comment: Using Taylor uses implicitly derivatives...

Comment: Using exponential series for $e^{x\log x}$. These series are taught in algebra before the Taylor series is taught in calculus.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that both current answers stray close to circular logic regarding the derivative of $a^x$. I offer this proof which instead defines $e^x$ and its derivatives and uses this to prove facts about $a^x$.

---

Define

$$\ln(x)=\int_{1}^x \frac{1}{t}dt$$

Note that here we are not assuming that $\ln(x)=\log(x)$ although we will eventually show this to be the case.

$1)$ For any $r\in\mathbb{R}$ we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x^r)=\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d}{du}\ln(u)$$

where $u=x^r$. Then

$$=rx^{r-1}\frac{1}{u}=\frac{rx^{r-1}}{x^r}=\frac{r}{x}$$

In a similar manner, we have

$$\frac{d}{dx} r\ln(x)=\frac{r}{x}$$

Since the derivatives are equal, we may conclude

$$\ln(x^r)=r\ln(x)+C$$

for some constant $C$. To find this, note that at $x=1$ we have

$$\ln(1)=\int_1^1\frac{1}{t}dt=0$$

Thus

$$0=\ln(1)=\ln(1^r)=r\ln(1)+C=C$$

We conclude that for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\ln(x^r)=r\ln(x)$.

$2)$ Consider

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}$$

We can bound the quantity by geometric arguements

$$\frac{1}{1+|x|}=\frac{1}{x}\cdot x\cdot \frac{1}{1+|x|}\leq \frac{1}{x}\int_1^{1+x}\frac{1}{t}dt\leq \frac{1}{x}\cdot x\cdot \frac{1}{1-|x|}=\frac{1}{1-|x|}$$

By the squeeze theorem we may conclude

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$$

$3)$ Define

$$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Note that we are not assuming that $e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}$. We have

$$\ln(e)=\ln\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)$$

Since $e\geq 1$ and $\ln(x)$ is continuous for all positive real numbers, this becomes

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Using the limit proved in $2)$ this becomes

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot \frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1$$

$4)$ This then implies

$$\ln(e^x)=x\ln(e)=x\cdot 1=x$$

Since both $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$ are increasing functions on their domains, this is enough to conclude that these are inverse functions.

$5)$ We will now state the [inverse function theorem](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/03%3A_Derivatives/3.7%3A_Derivatives_of_Inverse_Functions):

Suppose that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are inverse functions. Then

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{1}{g'(f(x))}$$

Using this with $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$ gives us

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=\frac{1}{\left.\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)\right|_{e^x}}=e^x$$

as desired.

$6)$ With this, we can now construct the Taylor series for $e^x$ about $x=0$. By induction, we have that

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

and it is not difficult to show that the series converges absolutely with an infinite radius of convergence. However, we already know that $\ln(x)$ is the inverse function of this series. We conclude that $\log(x)=\ln(x)$.

$7)$ Finally, we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}a^x=\frac{d}{dx} e^{\ln(a^x)}=\frac{d}{dx} e^{x\ln(a)}=\ln(a)e^{x\ln(a)}=\ln(a)e^{\ln(a^x)}=\ln(a)a^x$$

However, using the limit definition we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}a^x=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^{x+h}-a^x}{h}=a^x\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^{h}-1}{h}$$

We conclude

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^{h}-1}{h}=\log(a)$$

Comment: You're a god, I've been looking at this for like 2 hours. Thank you this is awesome.