# Differential for $2^x$ is $2^x \ln 2\, \Delta x$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, exponential-function, approximation

Here's a question from my calculus textbook:

> Show that when $\Delta x \to 0$, the increment in the function $y = 2^x$, corresponding to an increment $\Delta x$ in $x$, is, for any $x$, equivalent to the expression $2^x \ln 2\, \Delta x$.

We have that$$\Delta y = 2^{x + \Delta x} - 2^x = 2^x(2^{\Delta x} - 1).$$How do I show that as $\Delta x\to 0$, that $2^{\Delta x} - 1 \to \ln 2\,\Delta x$?

**EDIT:** Charles Hudgins in the comments says what we want to prove is a theorem that is usually merely cited. But I'm wondering if anyone can show this from first principles.

Comment: The existence of the limit is a theorem (one you shouldn't have to prove directly in a calc class. Requires a result on convex functions). But that it is equal to the claimed value is essentially a definition. The work you need to show depends on how you have defined things.

Comment: This is a hop, skip, and jump away from the definition of $e^x$ as a function.

Comment: $2^{\Delta x} - 1 \to \ln 2\,\Delta x$ makes little sense to me, since when computing a limit $\Delta x\to 0$, the variable $\Delta x$ should not appear in the result. What would make sense is to show that $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{2^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}=\ln(2)$, which is the same as showing that the derivative of $f(x)=2^x$ at $0$ is $\ln 2$. Since $2^x=e^{x\ln(2)}$, this is straightforward if you know the derivative of the exponential function and the Chain Rule.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} = \ln (a)$ without using L'hospital's.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640502/prove-lim-limits-h-to-0-fracah-1h-ln-a-without-using-lhospita)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be careful *how grouping* is done.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y'=(2^x)'=2^x \ln 2\to\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=2^x \ln 2 $$